# extract single element from a list and insert it into another list

Tags: python, list

I have a list formed like this

```
['s3://dx-datalake-modl-svil-3075-bucket-layer/DX/WDOS/VV_SALDI_TITOLO/c_acr=GE/c_giorno_t=20201231/', 's3://dx-datalake-modl-svil-3075-bucket-layer/DX/WDOS/VV_SALDI_TITOLO/c_acr=GE/c_giorno_t=20230531/']
```

and I should extract from it only the digits 20230531 and 20201231. I should put these in another list. How can I do?

I should get
['20230531','20201231']

Comment: Is your question how you can extract the number from one of those strings in the first place, or how to do the same thing for each element in a list?

Answer (score 2):

You can use re module which basically has tools for pattern matching/searching.

```
import re
input_list = [
    's3://dx-datalake-modl-svil-3075-bucket-layer/DX/WDOS/VV_SALDI_TITOLO/c_acr=GE/c_giorno_t=20201231/','s3://dx-datalake-modl-svil-3075-bucket-layer/DX/WDOS/VV_SALDI_TITOLO/c_acr=GE/c_giorno_t=20230531/'
]
output_list = []

for item in input_list:
    match = re.search(r'c_giorno_t=(\d+)', item)
    if match:
        output_list.append(match.group(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = ['s3://dx-datalake-modl-svil-3075-bucket-layer/DX/WDOS/VV_SALDI_TITOLO/c_acr=GE/c_giorno_t=20201231/',
    's3://dx-datalake-modl-svil-3075-bucket-layer/DX/WDOS/VV_SALDI_TITOLO/c_acr=GE/c_giorno_t=20230531/']

r = []

#iterate through the list
for x in l:
    
    #Get the index of 't=' and add 2 to get the index of the number
    idx = x.find('t=') + 2
    
    #get substring from idx to the last digit
    x = x[idx:-1]
    r.append(x)
print(r) #Output: ['20201231', '20230531']

#If you want in reverse order as shown in the question
r = r[::-1]
print(r) Output: ['20230531', '20201231']
```

Answer (score 1):

you could just iterate through the list and split "=".
then append to output_list.

```
output = []
for item in list:
    parts = item.split("=")
    output.append(parts[-1][:-1])

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also achieve this by using regular expression too to extract it from list.

```
import re
# Your list of strings
strings = [
    's3://dx-datalake-modl-svil-3075-bucket-layer/DX/WDOS/VV_SALDI_TITOLO/c_acr=GE/c_giorno_t=20201231/',
    's3://dx-datalake-modl-svil-3075-bucket-layer/DX/WDOS/VV_SALDI_TITOLO/c_acr=GE/c_giorno_t=20230531/'
]
# Initialize an empty list to store the extracted digits
list = []
# Iterate over the strings in your list
for string in strings:
    digits = re.search(r'\d{8}', string)
    if digits:
        # Append the extracted digits to the list
        list.append(digits.group())
print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If using `re` module, use the function `findall`:

```
import re
re.findall("(?<=t=)\\d+", ' '.join(strings))

['20201231', '20230531']
```